# Prefill a flexform's value via TSConfig?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, tsconfig

How do I prefill a plugin's flexform value via TSConfig?
The goal is that when a user creates a new CE with that flexform, that field is already filled in.

This is how the field looks in the flexform.

```
<settings.fal.storage>
    <TCEforms>
      <label>LLL:EXT:fileviews/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_flexform.xlf:fileviews.falStorage</label>
        <config>
            <type>group</type>
            <internal_type>db</internal_type>
            <allowed>sys_file_storage</allowed>
            <size>1</size>
            <default>1</default>
            <maxitems>1</maxitems>
            <minitems>1</minitems>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.fal.storage>
```

I want to predefine it to storage n. We tried this code in Page TSConfig, but no luck yet.

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_content {
        pi_flexform {
            fileviews_allfilesteaser {
                sDEF {
                  settings\.fal\.storage.default = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe use `TCADefaults`?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You missed one level. `default` is not available directly below `[propertyName]`.</strike> There, only the [documented properties](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html) are available.

Also below `config`, there are only limited configuration options available (see [TSconfig Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html?highlight=tceform#config)):

```
TCEFORM.[tableName].[fieldName].[dataStructureKey].[flexSheet].[flexFieldName].config.[configurationOption] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not getting there yet though. Wdy think about this old article: http://labor.99grad.de/typo3-tca-default-werte-per-tsconfig-setzen/  where the author says: `# No chance!! TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.title.config.default = Mein Default-Titel`?

Comment: Seems to be the right answer. In the linked documentation about `config`, there's also a list of properties below config which can be modified - and there's no 'default' listed :-/ I will edit my wrong answer.
Strangely enough, https://www.riccabona.it/aktuelle-meldung/detail/artikel/flexform-felder-via-pagetsconfig-beeinflussen/ writes that it works - around the same time in 2016.

Comment: Correct link: https://www.riccabona.it/aktuelle-meldungen/detail/artikel/flexform-felder-via-pagetsconfig-beeinflussen/